# Sort the list values based on Created Date

Tags: apex, sort

```
List<Account> Acc// this list contains Account records.
Acc.Sort() is not working
```

How to sort the records based on Created Date? Basically i need the recently record from the Acc list

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I linked a couple of answers that include enough code to get you started with your requirement and an explanation of how they work. Hopefully these answers can get you to your objective. If these answers don't work, you can [edit] your question to include more details and let us know, and we'll be happy to reopen your question for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Account> Acc = [SELECT Id,Name from Account Order by CreatedDate DESC]
```

You dont need to use sort function separately.

Comment: i can't use SOQL query because i have to sort that list inside for loop